# KeyError: "word 'restrictions' not in vocabulary" while generating word embedding vectors for text, read from a textfile

Tags: python, deep-learning, text-files, word2vec

I have got this error: "KeyError: word 'restriction' not in vocabulary", when I read a text file to generate word embedding vectors, while the word 'restrictions' is in the text file. I wonder if my code for reading a textfile (a simple paragraph) is erroneous?

MY CODE IS WRITTN BELOW:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
# define training data
with open('D:\\test.txt', 'r') as file:
sentences = ""
#read from textfile
for line in file:
    for word in line.split(' '):
        sentences += word + ' '
# train model
model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1)
# summarize the loaded model
print(model)
# summarize vocabulary
words = list(model.wv.vocab)
# save model
model.save('model.bin')
# load model
new_model = Word2Vec.load('model.bin')
print(new_model)
print(str(model['restriction']))
```

**This error does not happen when I use pre-written sentences inside the code as follows:**

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
# define training data
sentences = [['this', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'sentence', 'for', 'word2vec'],  
                ['this', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'sentence'],  
                ['yet', 'another', 'sentence'],  
                ['one', 'more', 'sentence', 'with', 'restriction'],
                ['and', 'the', 'final', 'sentence']]
# train model
model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1)
# summarize the loaded model
print(model)
# summarize vocabulary
words = list(model.wv.vocab)
print(words)
# access vector for one word
print(model['sentence'])
# save model
model.save('model.bin')
# load model
new_model = Word2Vec.load('model.bin')
print(new_model)
print('the model prints: ')
print(model['restriction'])
```

Comment: Firstly, I would try un-indenting that whole block of file reading code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code showing the problem, examine `sentences` closely, after you've constructed it, to see if it is the format you expect (or anything at all like the `sentences` of the working case). I suspect it isn't.

Also, take a look at the disappointing model's list of words learned – the `words` variable you've created should suffice. It also may not look like the words you expect.

Specifically, this section of your code...

```
sentences = ""
for line in file:
    for word in line.split(' '):
        sentences += word + ' '
```

...makes `sentences` one long string, with lots of space-separated words. If you did that to the `sentences` in your working code, you'd no longer have a list, where each item is a list of tokens. (That's a good input format for `Word2Vec`.) Instead, you'd have one giant run-on string:

```
sentences = 'this is the first sentence for word2vec this is the second sentence yet another sentence one more sentence with restriction and the final sentence'
```

Try instead:

```
sentences = []  # empty list
# OOPS, DON'T DO: sentences = ""
for line in file:
    sentences.append(line.split(' '))
```

...then your `sentences` will be a list-of-lists-of-strings (like the working case), instead of just a string (like the broken case).

Comment: Thanks @gojomo. I think you are right. sentences of the textfile are not saved in variable sentences with the expected format, which is the main problem. But unfortunately your suggested code for reading the textfile did not work. I got this error when adding it to my code for reading the textfile: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'. And when I changed sentences to senyences[i], I got another error: IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Sorry, I meant only the line `sentences = []` (so it's a proper list), and inadvertently left erroneous `sentences = ""` in from my copy-and-paste of your original. Don't do `sentences = ""`. (I've commented-out the line with a warning in my answer.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your suggestion solved the error. One more tiny question: Do you think this code would work for generating word2vec vectors for non-English languages e.g., Turkish or Persian?

Comment: `Word2Vec` & related algorithms work on many languages. What's most important is: (1) 'word' units that are segmented in a way not-too-different from English. (Languages without spaces between words like some Asian languages, or compounding many word-fragments together like German, can need extra preprocessing before word2vec  works well.) (2) Lots of varied realistic data. So: it's worth a try, but you'll likely need to pay attention to data volume/quality, preprocessing, & model-tuning before your get *good* vectors for any new language or dataset.